# How to prevent grey background with Vuetify button that is using Vue router link?

Tags: material-design, vuetify.js, vue-router

When adding Vue-Router link like `to="/"` to my `v-app-bar-nav-icon`:

```
<v-app-bar fixed app>
  <v-app-bar-nav-icon v-else to="/">
    <v-icon>mdi-home-city</v-icon>
  </v-app-bar-nav-icon>
</v-app-bar>
```

The button gets a grey background (only) when I'm on the home page (`/`).

Is it a bug ?
How to prevent this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's rather unsusual to repurpose this element. Usually `v-app-bar-nav-icon` is there for toggling the navigation drawer visibility- it would be better to use some other element instead.

Your code, especially the `v-else` lets the icon dissapear. The `to="/"` part didn't change the icon color in my test.

Answer (score 0):

I used Chrome's `Inspect Element` feature and under the `Styles` tab I found find this:

```
.theme--light.v-btn--active::before {
  opacity: 0.18;
}
```

So just override this class and change its opacity to 0 will work.

I think this is intended, but not my favorite... :/